# ZK-Why Zk drop getFocus() or isFocus()?

Tags: focus, zk

I was trying to get if Window is focused or not so i gone through available method of Window class ,did not get any `getFocus();` or `isFocus();` method. Is there any reason to ZK drop this method ? There is only `focus()` method with void type.
I have a complex problem ,In my application single page have two parts left hand side contain **a.zul** and right part **b.zul**  and have tabs. I have to fire **CTRL** key event something like this if focus on **a.zul** then fire event on **A.Java** class and When focus on **b.zul** then fire event in **B.Java** class. But as i am not able to get focus its hard to determine which window or zul is focused now? ANy one know any other solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of elements (dom level elements) cannot receive focus, e.g., div, span, ul/li, table, tr, td, ..., etc

Also lots of widgets (ZK widgets) cannot receive (and do not handle) focus, e.g., window, div, label, grid, ..., etc

This is why there is no getFocus/isFocus methods by default since they are not that 'common' for a component, lots of components cannot receive focus, some of components work with 'default' focus (e.g., a, textbox) and some of components work with 'hand made' focus (e.g., listbox contains a dom element 'a' and play around it for focus).

You can try to listen to onFocus event or onClick event at server side to know which component is focused/clicked(selected), or override doFocus_(evt) method of widget and log the focused widget at client side for further processing.

But why do you need to fire onCtrlKey event manually? It will be fired from client to server automatically by default.

Comment: Actully i am working on CTRL key and in parent zul i have write ctrl key attribute with which method will be called now i am passing ctrl key to child modalWindow to fire event everything fine upto here but issue is that my pages have two parts as i explain above so in both part i am getting same viewmodal fired method which cause the issue

Comment: In my opinion, this case you can specify ctrlKey at these two parts and bind to two different commands instead of specify it at parent then post event.

Comment: yes but i used this functionality as a common so i added it into index.zul and passing ctlrl to corresponding viewmodel but if page have two view model then its a problem

Comment: Could you provide a sample to describe your scenario?